# How to set a default value dependent on the value of another attribute in an Entity / Model?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example, every time I want to create a new entity or model, there is an attribute called `global` that I need to set to **true** or **false** depending on its other attribute called `id` :

If the `id` is **0**, I want the `global` to be **true**

Entity :

```dart
class Folder extends Equatable {
  const Folder({
    required this.id,
    required this.global /// here i want this.global = (id == 0)
  });

  final int id;
  final bool global;

  @override
  List<Object> get props {
    return [
      id,
      global,
    ];
  }
}
```

Model :

```dart
class FolderModel extends Folder{
  FolderModel ({
    required this.id,
    required this.global,
  }) : super(
    id: id,
    global: global,
  );

  FolderModel copyWith({
    int? id,
    bool? global,
  }) {
    return FolderModel(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      global: global ?? this.global,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};
  
    result.addAll({'id': id});
    result.addAll({'global': global});
  
    return result;
  }

  factory FolderModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return FolderModel(
      id: map['id']?.toInt() ?? 0,
      global: map['global'] ?? false,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory FolderModel.fromJson(String source) => FolderModel.fromMap(json.decode(source));

}
```

Where should I add that, or should I create a special function to read that value ? or just don't add anything and everything is logic out of these classes ?

Comment: If `global` can be calculated from `id`, why is it a property and not just a getter?

Comment: Because i need to save it in the DB

Comment: If it can be calculated from another field, then it seems pointless to have it in the DB. It could be a calculated field there as well. But even if... you can use the getter when writing it to the DB.

Comment: You are right, then you would only do a getter of that value with that calculation right ? Would it be done in the Model or in the Entity ?

Comment: You can put it on both, or just where you need it. If writing to the database is the only point where you need it, then right there should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to make `global` a getter, since you don't use it anyway.

In case you *do* want the explicit option of having a global with an id, the simplest way to achieve this is:

```
class Folder {
  const Folder({
    required this.id,
    bool? global
  }) : global = (global ?? (id == 0));

  final int id;
  final bool global;
  
  @override
  String toString() {
      return 'id=$id, global: $global';
  }
}


void main() {
  const configurable = Folder(id: 17, global: true);
  const automaticGlobal = Folder(id: 0);
  const automaticNonGlobal = Folder(id: 17);
  
  print(configurable);
  print(automaticGlobal);
  print(automaticNonGlobal);
}
```

By making `global` a non-required named parameter, it is optional. If you set it, the value will be used, if you don't, the value will be calculated.

This will print:

```
id=17, global: true
id=0, global: true
id=17, global: false
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try use factory constructor :

```dart
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Folder extends Equatable {
  const Folder({required this.id, required this.global});

  final int id;
  final bool global;

  factory Folder.byId(int id, {bool? global}) {
    return Folder(id: id, global: global ?? id == 0);
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props {
    return [
      id,
      global,
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO this will work for your issue:

```js
class Folder extends Equatable {
  Folder({required this.id, required this.global
      }) {
    global = (id == 0);
  }

  int id;
  bool global;

  @override
  List<Object> get props {
    return [
      id,
      global,
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: While it "works", you had to remove the `final` qualifier. It also still requires you to pass something to `global`, although regardless of what you pass to it, it will be overwritten. That is probably very confusing for a normal user of the class.